# How to implement a timeout in an online reservation system

Tags: php, paypal, timeout

I am developing a online hotel reservation system and I have found the need to put a timer that limits the time a customer can finish his reservation. I am doing this because of some concurrency issues. The timer would span starting from the selection of rooms until after the payment is completed.

I am planning to use paypal but I am not sure if it has a timer feature ( the confirm payment button will be disabled once the time runs out ).

My flow goes like this:
Select Room Page -> customer information page (start timer) -> Payment (paypal) -> Result page

Any suggestions are welcome...
(I am new to web development)
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can always store an UNIX style time in a session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['start'] = time();
```

And when you want to finish it, you can get the timestamp difference (time elapsed) by subtracting the stored time from the current one:

`time() - $_SESSION['start'];`

Check http://php.net/time for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir... I was storing a timestamp on the database instead, but I'm looking for a way to stop the user fom completing the payment in paypal once his time is out...

Comment: I suppose it is really up to PayPal's API for to make such restrictions. You could always restrict a user from making a payment by redirecting him to paypal, but if he is already on the paypal page when his time runs out?